# How to iterate over List of Lists in Java?

Tags: java

I am reading a CSV file into a `List<String>`. However, my program creates a new List for each row in the CSV file. structure of the CSV file is shown below:

```
[KI , -3.370417, -168.734039, Kiribati]

[KM , -11.875001, 43.872219, Comoros]

[KN , 17.357822, -62.782998, Saint Kitts and Nevis]

[KP , 40.339852, 127.510093, North Korea]

[KR , 35.907757, 127.766922, South Korea]

[KW , 29.31166, 47.481766, Kuwait]

[KY , 19.513469, -80.566956, Cayman Islands]

[KZ , 48.019573, 66.923684, Kazakhstan]

[LA , 19.85627, 102.495496, Laos]
```

I want to be able to iterate over each of these lists and access items such as the "South Korea" or "KI".

However I cannot find an efficient way of doing so. My attempt is shown below for traversing the Lists in the method `distance()`:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {

    public static void distance(List<String> list) {
        
            //attempt
        for (List row : list) {
            for (Object item : row) {
                System.out.println(item + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        String file = "countries.csv";
        List<String> countries;

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String line = "";

        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null ) {
            List<String> nodes = Arrays.asList(line.split(","));
            countries = nodes;
            //System.out.println(countries);
            // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nodes));
        }
        System.out.println();

        distance(countries);
    }
}
```

Is there a way of iterating over and accessing elements of List of Lists?
.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Your code is more or less O(n) on the number of items in the list-of-lists (hard to know for sure, since it looks like there are a couple bugs, but you haven't told us the end goal), which is as good as it's going to get if you can't assume any ordering. You may want to read the items into a Map or such of you need repeated lookups, and if it fits into memory. If it doesn't fit into memory, it may be time to look into a real database. But without knowing what specific problem you're actually having, we can't offer a solution.

Comment: The code which you have provided does not compile because you are treating `countries` as a list of lists while it is only a list of string!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand your question, but in any case, your code does not compile because you are treating `countries` as a list of lists while it is only a list of String! here is a working version of your application:

```
package com.company;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void distance(List<List<String>> list) {

        for (List row : list) {
            for(Object item: row)
                System.out.println(item + "\t");

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String file = "countries.csv";
        List<List<String>> countries = new ArrayList<>();

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String line = "";

        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null ) {
            List<String> nodes = Arrays.asList(line.split(","));
            countries.add(nodes);
            //System.out.println(countries);
            // System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nodes));
        }
        System.out.println();

        distance(countries);
    }
}
```

I changed `countries = nodes;` to `countries.add(nodes);` which creates a list of `List<string>`, now if you want to access the last element of the inner list, you can do so like this:

```
System.out.println("Country: " + row.get(3));
```

I believe you would benefit a lot by reading on:

- how to initialize objects in Java.
- data structures such as `Array`, `LinkedList` and `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jackson (here you'll find documention of it https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/master/csv) to read CSV file.

you can try this code, in this way you can iterate the list easily.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvSchema;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class CsvUtils {

    private final static CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();


    /**
     * function to read SCV
     * @param clazz {@link Class}
     * @param file {@link File}
     * @param <T> {@link T}
     * @return List of object
     * @throws IOException must catch it
     */
    public static <T> List<T> read(Class<T> clazz, File file) throws IOException {
        CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(clazz).withHeader().withColumnSeparator(',');
        return mapper.readerFor(clazz).with(schema).<T>readValues(file).readAll();
    }


}
```

Comment: Sometimes it is better to code it out manually, especially if a beginner asks. Only use a library if it provides a major benefit to the whole application, not for such simple things.